# Run .exe file from SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, cmd, exe, xp-cmdshell

i am trying to open a .exe file from within an sql query or Job.

im using xp_cmdshell , it is enabled on the server

the .exe runs properly when i double click on it from my windows Explorer

but when i try to open it using xp_cmdshell it returns to me 1 row affected
and the row is null.

the .exe file is supposed to delete all the content from a certain table.
when i run the file from the windows explorer, the .exe deletes all the content of the above mentioned table, whereas when i try using xp_cmdshell the content of the table remain intact, which means the .exe file is not opened.

any ideas?? this is the code i'm using

exec master..xp_cmdshell  'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Digital_Library_Shamaa\ShamaaConsoleIndexer\Publish\setup.exe'

i have added the permission Everyone to the folder containing the above .exe file and all its sub folders!

Answer (score 0):

1) Run `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami'` to see which user you're trying to run the `exe` file

2) Did you enable :

```
USE master
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

3) Did you unblock the file ?

[image]

Comment: when i did the first step i go 2 rows : nt authority\system and the 2nd one null

any ideas?
Royi Namir

Comment: the file opens from windows explorer normally just from the sql query it doesn't! there is no such button "unblock" when i right click my .exe file! please help!

Comment: open task manager .  do you see the process of your exe file ?

Comment: Does this exe only deletes files ?

Comment: this .exe file executes changes on database tables and fires threads for indexing purposes! when i double click on the .exe file it works like a charm! i just need to be able to do that from within my sql query or JOB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71021/discussion-between-ghassan-and-royi-namir).

Comment: there is nothing in the log that is pointing to an error or whatsover, i have checked the log and it is stating first the xp_cmdShell was off and then i turned it on and set it to 1 and reconfigured,all the normal steps .
but what i just found out is when i log in to slq server using my Windows authentication,i can view my server agent,
but when i try to access using sql authentication, the server agents disappears!
what if the sql server is not able to open the file, it might be reaching it, but maybe it is not being able to open it?
what can i do please help me man!

Comment: I'm a bit busy right now. but I created a little test file. Create a  folder `c:\r\ ` then put inside it a jpg file named `1.jpg` so now you have `c:\r\1.jpg` now run the file from sql and see if it deletes the file. ( all the exe file doing is delete this specific `c:\r\1.jpg` file . tell me if it deletes it. http://www.filedropper.com/consoleapplication17